# How do I obtain the true column indices of a table cell?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I have a table cell, and I want to know which rows and columns it occupies.  For that purpose, I want to know the index of the leftmost column.

`.cellIndex` does not work; it only gives the index of the cell within its corresponding `<tr>` node’s `.cells` node list.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td, th').forEach(cell => {
  cell.textContent = `R${cell.closest('tr').rowIndex}C${cell.cellIndex}`;
  cell.classList = cell.cellIndex === +cell.dataset.x ? '' : 'bad';
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 0.25em; }
.bad { color: red; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr> <td data-x="0"> <td data-x="1"> <td data-x="2"> <td data-x="3">
  <tr> <td data-x="0"> <td data-x="1" colspan="2"> <td data-x="3">
  <tr> <td data-x="0"> <td data-x="1" rowspan="2"> <td data-x="2"> <td data-x="3">
  <tr> <td data-x="0"> <td data-x="2"> <td data-x="3">
  <tr> <td data-x="0"> <td data-x="1"> <td data-x="2"> <td data-x="3">
</table>
```

What is the way to obtain true column indices?

Comment: You might have to loop through the preceding cells in that row and add up their column spans